# Getting the HTTP verb inside the controller

Tags: php, http, laravel-4, restful-authentication

I'm using Laravel (version 4) on a project of mine and I was wondering if it would be possíble in any way to know the verb to my requisition inside a laravel's controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your exact Laravel version.

The current [docs say](http://laravel.com/docs/requests) there's a specific method in the Request object. Quoting:

```
$method = Request::method();

if (Request::isMethod('post'))
{
    //
}
```

but I don't have a 4.1 version to test with, though. In any case you can always access the `$_SERVER` superglobal - Laravel style, too:

```
echo Request::server('REQUEST_METHOD');
// will get you "GET", "POST", ecc.
```

Comment: Thank you, man. I read the entire docs and let this peace pass! Feel so dumb right now! =D

Comment: Yeah, I know very well how that feels like, I've done worse :D